# Aggregate a data frame in R by equally spaced time intervals

Tags: r, dataframe, time-series, aggregate

I want to aggregate the data by time and create equally spaced time intervals:

```
date<- c(as.POSIXct("2011-08-08 21:00:00"), as.POSIXct("2011-08-08 21:26:00"))
value<-c(1,2)
dt<-data.frame(date, value)

DT<-aggregate(cbind(dt$value),list(cut(dt$date, breaks="10 min")),sum) 

dt:
2011-08-08 21:00:00 1
2011-08-08 21:26:00 2

DT:
2011-08-08 21:00:00 1
2011-08-08 21:20:00 2
```

What I want:

```
2011-08-08 21:00:00 1
2011-08-08 21:10:00 NA
2011-08-08 21:20:00 2
```

Is there anyway to do this without using zoo or xts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming by your last line that you are trying to avoid using packages.

Sticking with base R, you can try `tapply`, but your dates will become the `rownames` (or `names`, if you skip the `data.frame` step):

```
data.frame(value = tapply(cbind(dt$value),
                          list(cut(dt$date, breaks="10 min")),
                          sum))
#                     value
# 2011-08-08 21:00:00     1
# 2011-08-08 21:10:00    NA
# 2011-08-08 21:20:00     2
```